# RSA_public_decrypt fails with a -1

Tags: authentication, encryption, openssl, rsa

I have a small react-native app that signs a message with an RSA private key. Here is the code segments that signs the message (**Hello World** in this case)

```
import { RSA } from 'react-native-rsa-native'

RSA.generateKeys(2048).then(keys => {
    RSA.signWithAlgorithm('Hello World', keys.private, RSA.SHA512withRSA).then(message => {
        console.log(message)
        // "TfAgdPqm+CPxAqxPdV1jfGQvZAZ+uQ/sAlaHCK0ZvHKnRhHnKj+I2PHZhHhM5tJ14hgPd9H48Pe5\nbPFXj0KTk/Ty8YOcd7h98STwmJyNzlqM03Get42q9fD//ofyFZfQrm3R2OZjgOlQ5myepqko8+nk\nobuawPNVsi2Eu+N6PBBAW86hX9pRfKP3gkrOCK8ae1k9O9ysOXucSguaV1++WHkv30O2mN2rsEAT\nATi6SFxYry6n9G+6gIxOyWF9X8qleg3dJgURAPwpD1SWnTOb2hZChpYOWnIreqO9hGQlTgMVzDx3\nncdGpuJ4EatW4ETBO9ox+s7OeqI4TQxt0kH09Q==\n"
    })
})
```

Now, I'm trying to verify (and in turn decrypt with the corresponding public key) the signature from a C program using OpenSSL's **RSA_public_decrypt** function. Here is the C code with the public key and the encrypted signature embedded into it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>


unsigned char key[] = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBCgKCAQEAmz6Z6jk2qQ0kPUNCcxTz/dJmUEdVWDWeOeTKS2jwSd5vlwqPHH8Y\nC5BVCuDJ2EKRmB3k18bIDrBqqG9mguqimCY5FA2E5FyIWMOswrnvgzmmyO0RFLUK\nBNUhQ2A3fegL3TNwU8S9bWZV4Bb4zgGIq51QVL8r9yCNd2TC5Y0PHvT36ZbP1W/K\nAvfSsJZYarbVz3QhcEnSXcnllK8AADqMp6jX6zf6vpIEDaf+gs3wg6ubaq7Du81I\nc7iMHfxNL6Uv803T0LKJLOiDXsZZB4K8AKLy86ZsXIkU8NHb2fX4bFvncBZraWGD\nreEDlMNMfwxX6UJR/scnj9R/spiV+9XJqwIDAQAB\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n";


//digest for "Hello World"
unsigned char encrypted[] = "TfAgdPqm+CPxAqxPdV1jfGQvZAZ+uQ/sAlaHCK0ZvHKnRhHnKj+I2PHZhHhM5tJ14hgPd9H48Pe5\nbPFXj0KTk/Ty8YOcd7h98STwmJyNzlqM03Get42q9fD//ofyFZfQrm3R2OZjgOlQ5myepqko8+nk\nobuawPNVsi2Eu+N6PBBAW86hX9pRfKP3gkrOCK8ae1k9O9ysOXucSguaV1++WHkv30O2mN2rsEAT\nATi6SFxYry6n9G+6gIxOyWF9X8qleg3dJgURAPwpD1SWnTOb2hZChpYOWnIreqO9hGQlTgMVzDx3\nncdGpuJ4EatW4ETBO9ox+s7OeqI4TQxt0kH09Q==\n";


unsigned char decoded_encrypted[4096] = {0}, decrypted[4096] = {0};


int main() {

    RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
    BIO *keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void *) key, -1);
    if (keybio == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create key BIO\n");
        return -1;
    }
    rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(keybio, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
    if (rsa == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create RSA\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int result = EVP_DecodeBlock((unsigned char *) decoded_encrypted, (const unsigned char *) encrypted, strlen((const char *) encrypted));
    printf("\n----------%s(%d)------------\n", decoded_encrypted, result);



    // result = RSA_public_decrypt(strlen((const char *) decoded_encrypted), decoded_encrypted, decrypted, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);
    // printf("\n----------%s(%d)------------\n", decrypted, result);
    // ERR_print_errors(keybio);



    // const unsigned char m[] = "Hello World";
    // result = RSA_verify(NID_sha1, (const unsigned char *) m, strlen((const char *) m), (unsigned char *) encrypted, strlen((const char *) encrypted), rsa);
    // printf("\n----------(%d)------------\n", result);


    RSA_free(rsa);
    BIO_free(keybio);

    return 0;
}
```

But the decryption(verification) is not taking place as **RSA_public_decrypt**(**RSA_verify**) failing with a -1(0) return value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: (1) Whenever a libcrypto routine returns an error indication [look at the errror queue (aka error stack)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG8) (for libssl _sometimes_ you need SSL_get_error before ERR_\*). (2) Your 'encrypted' is base64-encoded. you can use EVP_DecodeBlock to get the actual (binary/raw) data to 'decrypt' (which you are correct is really signature-verify not encryption, but we are stuck with the name for historical reasons)

Comment: [RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-8.2) prefixes the hash `H` of the data with the digest algorithm identifier `ID`, in this case [`0x3051300d060960864801650304020305000440`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#page-47) for SHA512. [`RSA_public_decrypt`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_public_decrypt.html) doesn't remove this prefix, so it returns `ID || H`. It's easier to use the dedicated functions for signing/verifying, e.g. [`RSA_verify`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_verify.html), which simply returns `1` in case of success.

Comment: I've tried both of your approaches (as you see the modifications in the codes). But none seems to working. **EVP_DecodeBlock** is failing with -1. **RSA_public_decrypt** was already failing and so is **RSA_verify** (with return value 0).

Answer (score 0):

There are several minor flaws: For [`EVP_DecodeBlock`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_DecodeBlock.html) the line breaks (`\n`) must be removed. Note that there are various Base64-implementations on the Internet, some of which process Base64-encoded strings both with and without line breaks, e.g. the Base64 BIO filter [`BIO_f_base64`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BIO_f_base64.html) that considers line breaks by default (which can be changed with the flag [`BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/BIO_f_base64.html)). In this example, for simplicity's sake, `EVP_DecodeBlock` is used in conjunction with a signature *without* line breaks. The following code concerning [`RSA_public_decrypt`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_public_decrypt.html) works on my machine:

```
RSA* rsa = RSA_new();
...
// RSA_public_decrypt
// SHA512-ID: 3051300d060960864801650304020305000440
const unsigned char encrypted[] = "TfAgdPqm+CPxAqxPdV1jfGQvZAZ+uQ/sAlaHCK0ZvHKnRhHnKj+I2PHZhHhM5tJ14hgPd9H48Pe5bPFXj0KTk/Ty8YOcd7h98STwmJyNzlqM03Get42q9fD//ofyFZfQrm3R2OZjgOlQ5myepqko8+nkobuawPNVsi2Eu+N6PBBAW86hX9pRfKP3gkrOCK8ae1k9O9ysOXucSguaV1++WHkv30O2mN2rsEATATi6SFxYry6n9G+6gIxOyWF9X8qleg3dJgURAPwpD1SWnTOb2hZChpYOWnIreqO9hGQlTgMVzDx3ncdGpuJ4EatW4ETBO9ox+s7OeqI4TQxt0kH09Q==";

unsigned char decoded[258]; // length(encrypted) / 4 * 3, possibly padded with 0, see EVP_DecodeBlock
EVP_DecodeBlock(decoded, encrypted, strlen((const char*)encrypted));

unsigned char decrypted[19 + 64]; // length(hash-ID) + length(hash)
int decryptedLength = RSA_public_decrypt(RSA_size(rsa), decoded, decrypted, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING); // RSA_NO_PADDING reveals the padding (in conjunction with 256 bytes buffer) 

for (int i = 0; i < decryptedLength; i++)
    printf("%02x", decrypted[i]);
```

For [`RSA_verify`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/RSA_verify.html) the hash of the data must be used (instead of the data themselves). Furthermore `NID_sha512` must be applied (instead of `NID_sha1`), since SHA512 and not SHA1 is used in the react-native code. Add the following snippet to the above code:

```
// RSA_verify
const unsigned char hash[64] = { 0x2c, 0x74, 0xfd, 0x17, 0xed, 0xaf, 0xd8, 0x0e, 0x84, 0x47, 0xb0, 0xd4, 0x67, 0x41, 0xee, 0x24, 0x3b, 0x7e, 0xb7, 0x4d, 0xd2, 0x14, 0x9a, 0x0a, 0xb1, 0xb9, 0x24, 0x6f, 0xb3, 0x03, 0x82, 0xf2, 0x7e, 0x85, 0x3d, 0x85, 0x85, 0x71, 0x9e, 0x0e, 0x67, 0xcb, 0xda, 0x0d, 0xaa, 0x8f, 0x51, 0x67, 0x10, 0x64, 0x61, 0x5d, 0x64, 0x5a, 0xe2, 0x7a, 0xcb, 0x15, 0xbf, 0xb1, 0x44, 0x7f, 0x45, 0x9b };
int verified = RSA_verify(NID_sha512, hash, sizeof(hash), decoded, RSA_size(rsa), rsa);

printf("\n%d\n", verified);
```

In both snippets only the steps relevant for the illustration of the respective process are implemented, i.e. less important steps like removing the line breaks, determining the hash etc. were skipped.